# R plumber getting as excel (xlsx)

Tags: r, excel, plumber

I want to return or download excel for post response in plumber using R

I'm reading data frame and writing to xlsx:

*FileName: sample.R*

```
xlsx_df = read.xlsx(file="My_File.xlsx", sheetName="Overview", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, encoding="UTF-8")
write.xlsx(xlsx_df, file="Output_File.xlsx", sheetName="Sample_Sheet", row.names=F, showNA=F)
```

```
#* @serializer contentType list(type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
#* @get/excel
function(req, res){
  filename <- file.path(tempdir(), "Output_File.xlsx")
  write.xlsx2(iris, filename, row.names = FALSE)
  include_file(filename, res, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
}
```

*FileName: Plumber.R*

```
r <- plumb("sample.R")
r$run(port=8011)
```

When I look into response body I get some weird response, which is not readable.
and if I try to open the excel I get error **excel cannot open because file format or extension is invalid**

Can you please help me where i'm going wrong in generation of excel sheet?

Comment: Can you open the generated file, `Output_File.xlsx`?

Comment: yes @Panagiotis Kanavos i'm able to open the file in local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, hoping it'll be helpful to someone.

```
library(plumber)
library(xlsx)

#* @serializer contentType list(type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
#* @get /report/
api_get_report <-function(req, res){
  
  df <- data.frame(CHAR = letters, NUM = rnorm(length(letters)), stringsAsFactors = F)
  filename <- file.path(tempdir(), "alphabet.xlsx")
  write.xlsx(df, filename, sheetName="Alphabets", append=TRUE)
  attachmentString = paste0("attachment; filename=Output_File.xlsx", filename)
  
  res$setHeader("Content-Disposition", attachmentString)
  
  # Read in the raw contents of the binary file
  bin <- readBin(filename, "raw", n=file.info(filename)$size)
  
  #Return the binary contents
  bin
}
```

Answer (score 3):

using next release 1.0.0

```
library(xlsx)
library(plumber)

#* @get /excel
function(req, res){
  filename <- file.path(tempdir(), "Output_File.xlsx")
  on.exit(unlink(filename))
  write.xlsx2(iris, filename, row.names = FALSE)
  as_attachment(readBin(filename, "raw", file.info(filename)$size), basename(filename))
}
```